# Duplicated id in android designer even though there is no element with such id

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Below you can find code of my layout
i see following error in the visual studio
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error       Within a layout, id's should be unique since otherwise "FindViewById<T> (Int32)" can return an unexpected view. TestApp`
`Duplicate "@id/linearLayout1 @id/linearLayout6 @id/textView1, already defined in this layout`
I don't even have anything with id `textView1` i tried to clean the project but it didn't help. Am i missing something here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" >
    <Toolbar
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6" >
        <TextView
        android:text="Smart app"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/smName" />
            <TextView
        android:text="1.0.0v"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/appVersion" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5" >
        <TextView
        android:text="S/N 01234"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/serialNumber" />
        <TextView
        android:text="21.01.2012 13:15"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/date" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/space1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" >
                            <TextView
        android:text="Logowanie"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login" />
        </LinearLayout>
         <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/space2" />
        <TableLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*" 
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout1" >
            <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Login"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/editPassword" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <EditText
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hasło"        
        android:id="@+id/editLogin" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" >
            <Button
        android:text="Zaloguj"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton" />
    <Button
        android:text="Wyjdź"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton" />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the layout file. Try `Invalidate caches/restart`

Comment: The xaml works for me. Try to delete the obj and bin folder to clean and rebuild. If this still does not work. Close the project to restart the VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restaring and rebuilding project helped, looks like visual studio glitch